# how to get outline tick using css?

Tags: html, css

[image]I am trying to add tick in my application .currently my background is `black`.could you please tell me how to add `outline tick`

heer is code
https://jsbin.com/cilocakedu/edit?html,css,output

```
.img {
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 0.5
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 5rem;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: you mean you want an empty tick and only border?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a checkbox that is transparent, but with a black outline.  You can try adding this to your .icon class:

```
color: transparent;
-webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
```

Note that '-webkit-text-stroke' works on most modern browsers:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke#Browser_compatibility